# Can't import RegexParsers

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to run a file from the Textbook using but my IDE tells me it can't resolve the `RegexParsers` when I try to extend it. Below is the code from the textbook. I added the `import` statement which my IDE tells me is unused.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class ExprParser extends RegexParsers {
  val number = "[0-9]+".r
  def expr: Parser[Any] = term ~ opt(("+" | "-") ~ expr)
  def term: Parser[Any] = factor ~ rep("*" ~ factor)
  def factor: Parser[Any] = number | "(" ~ expr ~ ")"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I solved this myself and I'll leave it up for anybody having a similar issue
add

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.5"
```

to your build.sbt file then click import project in the top right